# How to retain the same text in Textview(ProductQuantity) even though the listview is scrolled?

Tags: android, listview

i have a listview with  *Imagebutton (increaseProductQuantityImageview)* and *Textview(ProductQuantity)* in same row. i have set textview to 1 and  when Button is clicked i am updating the count in textview . the textview count is updated properly but when i scroll the listview the text in textview gets interchanged. **How to retain the same text in Textview(ProductQuantity) even though the listview is scrolled??**

code: this is my viewHolder class and getView method

```
static class ViewHolder {

    ImageButton increaseProductQuantityImageview;
    TextView productQuantity;
    ImageButton deleteCartItem;

}

 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview_items, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.increaseProductQuantityImageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.increaseProductQuantityImageview);
    viewHolder.productQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
    viewHolder.deleteCartItem = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteCartItem);


    viewHolder.productQuantity.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.increaseProductQuantityImageview.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.deleteCartItem.setTag(position);


    viewHolder.increaseProductQuantityImageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String quantity = viewHolder.productQuantity.getText().toString();
            int quantity_int = Integer.parseInt(quantity) + 1;
            viewHolder.productQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity_int));
            cartScreenItemsArrayList.get(position).setProductQuanity(quantity_int);
             CartScreenListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });


        // delete is working fine
    viewHolder.deleteCartItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int cartItemPosition = (int) v.getTag();
            cartScreenItemsArrayList.remove(cartItemPosition);
            CartScreenListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

I looked into several posts, but its not working.

Comment: Maintain values in arraylist with the values of your text/string, whatever, and retrieve them by index of arraylist as position scrolled in listview, and set normally.

Comment: @Androider i am doing it the same way , but its not working

Comment: you update the quantity only in `quantity_int`, which is a local variable. Where do you update it in your arraylist?

Comment: @TDG i updated after setting the ProductQuantity Textview but it is still the same